# how do i acquire a google fonts api key

Tags: api, fonts

I have followed a several bewildering sets of instruction, but have so far not been able to acquire the google fonts api key. I have navigated to the Developers Console, selected a Project, then to - APIs & auth - APIs. There are dozens upon dozens of API's to choose from, but NOT ONE that is either 'Google Fonts API' or 'Web Fonts Developer API' or indeed anything that contains the words 'Font' & 'API.' Truly frustrating. Can anyone help?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Google Fonts are available free without an API key, at the link below:

https://www.google.com/fonts

Simply select the fonts you need, and add it to collection. A little panel should show up at the bottom of your screen. On the upper-right corner of the panel, click on "Use", and about halfway down the page you'll find the code snippet for you to use. Again, no API key is needed.